# PHP Mail is not sending

Tags: php, email

I have a PHP script which is supposed to send out a basic email.

```
$to      = '***@awakenstudios.net';
$subject = 'the subject 03';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@okteenchallenge.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@okteenchallenge.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Works well and fast, the strange thing is we are not receiving any email being sent to any of the domains being hosted on the same server. If I change this to a gmail address, it works, but when change it back to anything else, the message isnt received.

Comment: Did you check in spams ?

Comment: Yes. Its not in spam.